# Convert Chrome extension manifest V2 to V3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```json
 "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "ABC PRO"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "check.js"
        ],
        "all_frames": false
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "bg.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "cookies",
        "management",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.abc.com/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [the official migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: I tried but getting error 'webRequestBlocking' requires manifest version of 2 or lower.                       Unchecked runtime.lastError: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest.

Comment: As the migration guide says, ManifestV3 disallows the blocking webRequest.

Comment: Mean we cannot able to use this ??

Comment: or any other way to use this

Comment: The migration guide explains everything.

Comment: I'm not able to find can you please hight for me

Comment: Search for "webrequest" in the article.

Comment: can you please provide user agent  change code using  new declarativeNetRequest

Comment: It depends on what your code is currently doing. Show [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
            for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
                if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
                    details.requestHeaders[i].value = value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders }
        }, { urls: [key] }, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);

Comment: See [examples in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) and search for `modifyHeaders` (they use responseHeaders but you'll use requestHeaders).